# Page with multiple validation groups always returns TRUE for Page.IsValid

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have two validation groups and two validation summaries on my page. Controls belong to either of two groups and there is a button for each group that performs the validation for each.

I can't get `Page.IsValid` to work; it always returns true regardless of the validity of the controls on the page. Is there a different way to validate only particular groups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try performing `Page.Validate` before you check `Page.IsValid` like:

```
this.Page.Validate("ValidationGroup");
if (this.Page.IsValid)
{
   ...
}
```

Where `"ValidationGroup"` is the name of your validation group. If you use the `Page.Validate()` method without a group name parameter the validation groups are ignored and all controls are validated.